# nodejs/pm2 keeps saying cannot read certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, pm2

Basically, I have a letsencrypt certificate.
It is owned by root, as it should. However, I first created a ssl-group, added www-data to it and then chgroup -R all the /etc/letsencrypt directory.

My app is in /var/www/app, which is owned by www-data.

If I create a simple test.js file like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const key = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem');
const cert = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem');
console.log("cert",cert);
console.log("key",key);
```

When I run it, it works. I can see the buffer from the file.

Now, the real app is actually run through pm2.
I run it with:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.json
```

In server.js I also try to read the certificate like I do in test.js. But what happens is that I get this error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'
```

Looking at the file in the terminal, it gives this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root ssl-group 43 Feb 28 07:48 /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem -> ../../archive/example.com/privkey1.pem
```

Doing a

```
vi /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

while logged in as www-data also show the content of the file.

So what is the problem? Isn't it www-data that is actually running the app? Running ps -aux I can see this:

```
www-data   15503  0.1  6.6 852008 66232 ?        Ssl  07:58   1:07 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/var/www/.pm2)
root       15768  0.0  5.2 644908 52160 ?        Ssl  08:03   0:01 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)
www-data   33543  110  6.4 666576 63888 ?        Rsl  19:03   0:01 node /var/www/app/server.js
```

A couple of pm2 processes, but the app itself seems to be running by www-data. So why it cannot be read? I mean, if there was a user named pm2 or pm2user, I would add it to the ssl-group. I also tried it, but get the error: no such a user. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, rebooting sever solved the problem.